# Unable to route manually by changing route path in address bar when using createCustomElement in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a basic Angular microapp which has a Single feature module called root-test. In roo-test module I have child components called feature-one and feature-two.
Angular version - 10.2.4
node version - 14.24.1
Test module has its own routing file which also defines the route path configs for the child components. Following is the code for root-test-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FeatureOneComponent } from './feature-one/feature-one.component';
import { FeatureTwoComponent } from './feature-two/feature-two.component';
import { RootTestComponent } from './root-test.component';


const routes: Routes = [
 {
    path:'',component:RootTestComponent
 },
 {
  path:'one',component:FeatureOneComponent
},
{
  path:'two',component:FeatureTwoComponent
}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class RootTestRoutingModule { }
```

Code for root-test.module.ts

```
import {  NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RootTestRoutingModule } from './root-test-routing.module';
import { RootTestComponent } from './root-test.component';
import { FeatureOneComponent } from './feature-one/feature-one.component';
import { FeatureTwoComponent } from './feature-two/feature-two.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    RootTestComponent,
    FeatureOneComponent,
    FeatureTwoComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RootTestRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  exports:[   RootTestComponent,
    FeatureOneComponent,
    FeatureTwoComponent]
})
export class RootTestModule {
  


 }
```

Code for app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Injector, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RootTestModule } from './root-test/root-test.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RootTestModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  // bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {

  }

 ngDoBootstrap() {
   const myMicroElement = createCustomElement(AppComponent, { injector: this.injector });
   customElements.get('my-app') || customElements.define('my-app', myMicroElement);
 }
 }
```

Code for app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FeatureOneComponent } from './root-test/feature-one/feature-one.component';
import { FeatureTwoComponent } from './root-test/feature-two/feature-two.component';
import { RootTestComponent } from './root-test/root-test.component';


const routes: Routes = [
//  {
//     path:'root',
//     loadChildren: () => import('./root-test/root-test.module').then(m => m.RootTestModule)
//  },
{
  path:'root',component:RootTestComponent
},
 {
  path:'one',component:FeatureOneComponent
},
{
  path:'two',component:FeatureTwoComponent
}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Code for app.component.html

```
<h4>hello</h4>
<button (click)="routeToView()">Route</button>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Code for app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'microapp-test';

  constructor(private _router: Router) {}

  public routeToView(): void {
this._router.navigate(['one'])
  }
}
```

Code for index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MicroappTest</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- <app-root></app-root> -->
  <my-app></my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

I am serving the app in localhost using npm start. When I am manually the route path in my browser to "http://localhost:4200/one" its not routing to feature-one component but if I am routing programmatically using a button click with Router's navigation method then I am able to navigate.

I tried using hash location strategy but no good.